# Delete first 3 characters of string in Python

Tags: python, string, replace

I'm trying to delete up some initial preceding characters in a string in Python 2.7. To be more specific, the string is an mx record that looks like `10 aspmx2.googlemail.com`. I need to delete the preceding number (which can be single or double digits) and space character.

Here is the code I've come up with thus far, but I'm stuck

```
mx_name = "10 aspmx2.googlemail.com"
for i in range(0,3):
    char = mx_name[i]
    if char == "0123456789 ":
        short_mx_name.replace(char, "")
```

For some reason, the if statement is not working correctly and I fail to see why. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: `if char == "0123456789 "` means is `char` exactly the whole of `"0123456789 "` rather than in there somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `re.sub`:

```
import re
mx_name = "10 aspmx2.googlemail.com"
new_name = re.sub("^\d+\s", '', mx_name)
```

Output:

```
'aspmx2.googlemail.com'
```

Regex explanation:

`^`:anchor for the expression, forcing it to start its search at the beginning of the string

`\d+`:finds all digits until a non numeric character (in this case the space) is found.

`\s`: empty whitespace, must be included in this example so that the substitution also catches the space between the digit and email.

In short, `^\d+\s` starts the search at the beginning of the string, finds all proceeding digits, and lastly targets the space to make sure that the regex is not scanning part of the email.

Comment: Can you just explain the significance of "^\d+\s"

Comment: Isn't this a little heavyweight when you can just do `mx_name.split(' ', 1)[1]`?

Comment: @glibdud it is simpler to use `mx_name.split(' ', 1)[1]`, however, I believe this solution is more precise.

Comment: Thank you Ajax. I believe this answer most handles the problem at hand most directly. Also, thank you for the further explanation. Cheers.

Comment: @J.Behnken glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

The minimum modification to your code would be this:

```
mx_name = "10 aspmx2.googlemail.com"
short_name = mx_name[:]
for i in range(0,3):
    char = mx_name[i]
    if char in "0123456789 ":
        short_name = short_name.replace(char, "", 1)
```

Your `if` was checking if the char WAS `1234567890`, not if it was included in that set. Also including the 1 is needed to avoid deelting digits and spaces further in the string.

Comment: That would allow two spaces at the start.

Comment: Not true due to the range limit

Comment: Also, `replace()` returns a new string, it doesn't edit in place.

Comment: Doing this only replaces the space character for some reason. Output is `10aspmx2.googlemail.com`

Answer (score 0):

```
mx_name.split()[1]
```

Output:

```
'aspmx2.googlemail.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `split` function

```
mx_name = "10 aspmx2.googlemail.com"
mx_name_url = mx_name.strip().split(' ')[1]
# aspmx2.googlemail.com
```

Using `slice` function

```
mx_name = "10 aspmx2.googlemail.com"
mx_name[3:]
# aspmx2.googlemail.com
```

Comment: He stated that the number could be one or two digits, so a static slice won't work. The `split()` is probably the best option, although you may want to add a second argument of 1 in case there are spaces later in the line.

Comment: The problem with this is that the number can be single or double digit, which means the range of characters to replace can be either 0:2 or 0:3, depending, so a static slice wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex :

```
import re

pattern=r'\b[\d\s]{1,3}\b'

string='10 aspmx2.googlemail.com'

new_string=re.sub(pattern,"",string)
print(new_string)
```

output:

```
aspmx2.googlemail.com
```

with single digit:

`string='1 aspmx2.googlemail.com'`  then output:

```
aspmx2.googlemail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `regex` for that; There are plenty of regex answers to this question but if you want a more abstract solution you can use:

```
m = "10 aspmx2.googlemail.com"
match = re.search('(?:\s)(\w.*@.*\.)', m)
match.group(1)

'aspmx2.googlemail.com'
```

This pattern will match **any email address after the first space**.

- `(?:\s)` - non capturing space char
- `(\w.*@.*\.)` - matches alphanumeric character and the underscore followed by `@` and anything after in its own group

This will match `4123   name@email.com` or `some_text name@email.com` etc.